# WCF between ASP MVC 5 web application and winforms application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, wcf, asp.net-mvc-5

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to have an ASP MVC 5 website which can take orders and from the web site, when an order is placed, I would like the information related to the order (items, prices, customer ect..) to be passed to my windows form application for further processing and to display it. I am led to believe that WCF is the best way forward with this however finding examples for resources for my requirements is proving more difficult than initially anticipated, does anyone know where i could find more information/examples on this or point me in the right direction? The examples I have read so far do not appear to meet my requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fundamentally an architecture question. Normally in such a system there would not be a direct communication between applications. Instead they share data store, usually a database. This approach works where there are any number of providers and consumers of data running at the same time.

The way your question is worded implies that there is only ever one instance of a WinForms app. While I've seen that done on more than one occasion, it has never been a good idea. If it's a service, implement a service. Using a client app as a service requires a user session and a shell instance. A much better arrangement would be a service and a client app providing UI for the service and communicating with it via WCF. Your service and your web app can share a database.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention I have a SQL database at the back end. But I like the sound of the approach much more, I'll take it on board. Thank you for you help.